# Custom Angular 2+ Stepper module

Tags: angular8, stepper

At the beginning I would like to say that I know that there is ready to use stepper from CDK or Materials but I would like to create "my own" in order to learning angular 8.

To be honest I don't know where I should search help now that is why I decided to write here. Maybe someone give me some advices and I will publish my work at the end.

So let's begin:
The index HTML code looks like that:

```
<stepper>
<step>
    <ng-template step-label>First name</ng-template>
    <input placeholder="First name" required>
    <div>
        <button >Next</button>
    </div>
</step>
<step>
    <ng-template step-label>Last name</ng-template>
    <input placeholder="Last name" required>
    <div>
        <button >Next</button>
    </div>
</step>
<step>
    <ng-template step-label>Address name</ng-template>
    <input placeholder="Address" required>
    <div>
        <button >Next</button>
    </div>
</step>
</stepper>
```

Components + directive

```
@Directive({selector: '[step-label]'})
export class StepLabel{
    constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>){};
}

@Component({selector: 'step-header', templateUrl: 'step-header.html'})
export class StepHeader{ 

    @Input() label: TemplateRef<StepLabel>;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'step',
    template: '<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>'
})
export class Step{ 

    @ViewChild(TemplateRef, {static: true}) content: TemplateRef<Step>;
    @ContentChild(StepLabel, {static: true}) label: TemplateRef<StepLabel>;

}

@Component({selector: 'stepper', templateUrl: './stepper.html'})
export class Stepper implements AfterContentInit {
    stepsArray = [];
    @ContentChildren(Step) steps: QueryList<Step>;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.stepsArray = this.steps.toArray();
    }
}
```

stepper.html

```
 <div class="header-steps" style="bordeR: 1px solid green; padding: 10px;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let step of stepsArray; let i = index; let isLast = last">
        <step-header [label]="step.label"></step-header>
    </ng-container>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;" class="content-steps">      
    <div *ngFor="let step of stepsArray; let i = index">
        <ng-container *ngIf="step" [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.content"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

step=header.html

```
<div class="step-label">
  <ng-container *ngIf="label" [ngTemplateOutlet]="label.template"></ng-container>
</div>
```

I have updated whole "basic" project. It works.
I have one quesition. Why in the Directive StepLabel have to be constructor.
I tried to add somethink like that :

```
@ViewChild(TemplateRef, {static: true}) template: TemplateRef<StepLabel>;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure that i follow - what do you mean by "Why in the Directive StepLabel have to be constructor." ?

Comment: I guess i see what you mean - why TemplateRef should be injected through constructor and not ViewChild. Directives does not template so it does not make any sense to use ViewChild which searches in template.

Answer (score 1):

In your step component's template wrap ng-content in ng-template

```
template: '<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>'
```

And then get template using `ViewChild`

```
@ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true }) content: TemplateRef<any>;
```

In the end you'll get something like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'step',
    template: '<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>'
})
export class Step { 
    @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true }) content: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you explain why template of selector 'step' have to be like that?

Comment: ngTemplateOutlet directive requires TemplateRef. One way to get it is by using ng-template. So by wrapping ng-content into ng-template you are basically getting content of your element into TemplateRef.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated project, I have one more question (about constructor). If u can please answer.